# How wany ways can you arrange the word MATHEMATICS such that consonants should be in alphabetical order?

Tags: combinatorics

How wany ways can you arrange the word MATHEMATICS such that consonants should be in alphabetical order?

I considered the consonants as one letter and then divided by $2!$ because of a repeating vowel. Thus, getting $\frac{11!}{7!2!}$$=3,960$. Is there anything wrong with my solution?

Comment: The consonants need not be together and yet be in alphabetical order such as $CAHAMEMSITT$. Your way of counting doesn't count such strings.

Comment: You generate an arrangement by replacing each consonant by, say, X, then picking a random permutation of XAXXEXAXIXX, then replacing the Xs by the original consonants in alphabetical order? Sounds correct to me. The answer looks correct too.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.  Considering the consonants as one letter suggests that they are consecutive.  However, as Anurag A pointed out in the comments, the consonants do not need to be consecutive.

The word MATHEMATICS has eleven letters, including seven consonants and four vowels.  Choose two of the eleven positions for the As, one of the remaining nine positions for the E, and one of the remaining eight positions for the I.  Once you have done so, there is only one way to fill the remaining seven positions with the seven consonants so that they appear in alphabetical order.

> Therefore, the number of distinguishable arrangements of the letters of the word MATHEMATICS in which the consonants appear in alphabetical order is $$\binom{11}{2}\binom{9}{1}\binom{8}{1}$$

Comment: That solution seems to be exactly what OP is going for though, since OP has the correct answer. His formulation seems inaccurate, but I believe by "I considered the consonants as one letter" he means he treats all consonants as indistinguishable.

Comment: @Magma Yes OP's solution is correct. It effectively accounts for all the "duplicates" in the $11!$ permutations. It doesn't depend on the position of the consonants. In fact, ${11 \choose 2} \cdot 9 \cdot 8 = \frac{11!}{7!2!}=3960$